# Is there a way to remove method calls in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to catch and remove method calls in my Rails models in certain cases.

I'd like something like the `remove_method`, but that removes method calls.

For example, if I have a `before_save` callback in a model, I may want to catch it using a module that's extended into the class, and remove or prevent the `before_save` from firing.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:**

The pervious answer I posted does not work - not sure if it ever did, but I vaguely recall using in the past.  To skip callbacks, in the context of a subclass, for example, you should use `skip_callback`.  Example of the usage:

```
skip_callback :save, :before, :callback_method_name
```

Or if you want to skip callbacks under a for a particular condition:

```
skip_callback :save, :before, :callback_method_name, if: :some_condition_true?
```

There is also a `reset_callbacks` method that takes the callback type as a parameter.  For example, `reset_callbacks :save`.  The callbacks can be accessed via the class methods, `_save_callbacks`, `_create_callbacks`, etc.  I would use caution when using `reset_callbacks` since it appears that Rails itself is defining callbacks for associations, namely, `:before_save_collection_association`.

If you're talking about just regular Ruby objects, you can override methods in subclasses.  Just define a method with the same name as the superclass.  You can also override base class methods in a subclass by including a module which defines the same instance methods as the base class.

Comment: In what context can you use this? I'm curious

Comment: This is good for Rails callbacks, but what about any Ruby methods. Validation, includes, etc.. all of those are method calls. I'd like to hook into any of them. Is there way?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried clearing `before_save` like this:

```
before_save ->{}
```